# Can boot put in 2 disk partition be a backup?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, raid

I'm rookie of ubuntu even linux.
My disk topology as below
[image]

Now my boot in sda1 and can open OS during raid and sda only.
my question is can I put boot in sdb1 and can open OS during raid and sdb only?
I try copy all sda1 data to sdb1 via dd, but still can not open via sdb1, do I miss some step? or I just need to modify grub? If yes, how to modify?

Thanks!